# Vertical border between floating DIVs using CSS

Tags: html, css, border

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child-1'>Some text goes here</div>
    <div id='child-2'>Different text goes here</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

I also have the following CSS

```
#parent {
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}

#child-1 {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}

#child-2 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Now, the contents of the child DIVs (**child-1** and **child-2**) could be anything, so eventually **child-1** might have longer height than **child-2**, or **child-2** might have a longer height than **child-1**.

What I want to do, is have a vertical line between **child-1** and **child-2**, and this line has the length of the DIV that is of longer height. I tried border on both DIVs, (right border for **child-1** and left border for **child-2**), but this is not a good idea, because the line will appear thick where the two DIVs touch each other and then thin for the extended part.

How can I do that? I also like to use CSS only if possible, no jQuery nor JavaScript. If you think extra DIVs are needed then this is OK though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I tried border on both divs, (right border on child-1 and left border on div-2, but this is not a good idea, because the line will appear thick where the two divs touch each other and then thin for the extended part.

That's a good way to go, actually. The final step, though, is to give the right div a negative left margin of 1px (assuming the border is 1px wide), so that the two borders overlap.

```
#child-1 {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

#child-2 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Another option is to use `display: table` on the parent and then `display: table-cell` on the columns, and then have a single border line between them.

Comment: Hmm, I am leaning towards the `display: table` solution. I will try it, I might stil ask more question :)

Comment: What if the first div is larger than second?

Comment: @Amal? In what situation? Either way, it doesn't matter. @Greeso: the negative 1px margin is a tried and tested method, so don't be afraid of it. :-)

Comment: Believe it or not, the negative margin solution worked, and the display-table solution did not. I am happy with the first solution. Thanks Ralph. :)

Answer (score 5):

The simple one:

```
elements {
  border-left: black solid 1px;
}

elements:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use

```
border-left:1px solid #color;
margin-left:2px;
```

and

```
border-right:1px solid #color;
margin-right:2px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also give `border-right: 1px solid #000;` only to your first div if this div is longer than second div and if second div is longer you could assign `border-left: 1px solid #000;` only to your second div.

Comment: But I do not know which is which, I do not have control of the content. I do not want to use jQuery or JavaScript to check which is longer then assign the border.